# How can I reduce the amount of cubes in a 3D geometry using python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have been given a dataset containing about 1.4 million rows of x0,y0,z0 and colour data. The task is to create a 3D plot of the data using 2x2x2m cubes in their correct colour. I have been able to create a working 3D plot if I only use the first 100 rows of the data but if I run the code for the entire dataset it crashes because the amount of data is too large. The majority of the small cubes have the same colour though and therefore can be combined into larger cubes, reducing the amount of cubes that needs to be plotted. My question therefore is if there is an easy way in Python to combine the small cubes into bigger cubes.

Sample code I am using:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"example_data.txt",  delimiter=",", names=["x", "y", "z", "soil"])
filtered_data = data[data["soil"] >= 0]
print(filtered_data.head())

cubes_list = []
for _, row in filtered_data.iterrows():
    color = "yellow" if row["soil"] > 1 else "grey"
    cube = create_cube(row["x"], row["y"], row["z"], cube_size=2, color=color)
    cubes_list.append(cube)
print("Amount of cubes:", len(cubes_list))
```

Output of sample code:

[image]